# angularJSでコントロール間の操作について

Tags: angularjs

angularJSで、あるコントローラーから他のコントローラー内にある特定の処理を実行させたいのですが、方法はあるのでしょうか？

例
HTML側
ng-clickでコントローラーAにあるsampleA()を呼び出し
↓
JS側
コントローラーAのsampleAからコントローラーBのsampleB()を実行

Answer (score 0):

`$rootScope`から`$broadcast`することで、`$rootScope`の子孫、つまりすべての`scope`に対してイベントを送れます。

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/JEIXXecDRbzlqTvafRbs?p=preview)

### Controller A

```
myApp.controller('A', ['$scope','$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.sampleA = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('myevent');
  };
}]);
```

### Controller B

```
myApp.controller('B', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('myevent', function(event, ...args) {
    $scope.sampleB();
  });
  $scope.sampleB = function() {
    // 何かする
  }
}]);
```

参考
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446755/on-and-broadcast-in-angular